# Stuck at the login page after running Matlab script

Tags: 14.04, login

My system (Ubuntu 14.04) got stuck after I ran a Matlab script. So I powered off the machine and tried to restart. Initially, it showed some errors and once it came to the login page it redirected back to the login page.

I have tried all sort of things, yet failed to fix the problem. I tried updating, upgrading and reinstalling the Nvidia driver. Now, no errors pop up, but I still can't go beyond the login page. In safe mode, everything works, but in the regular process, it gets stuck at the login page.

Can you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Actually, I could not resolve this. Have to reinstall ubuntu again! It was painful